# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, installer ignores one of the logical drives

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

On my PC, where I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside existing Windows 7, there is a single physical drive consisting of:

- System Reserved / 100 MB NTFS / System, Active, Primary Partition
- C: / 117 GB NTFS / Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition
- D: / 180 GB NTFS / Primary Partition

D: partition is empty and this is where I want to install Ubuntu.

However, when I select "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" in the installer, there is a single proposed drive: SCS1 (0,0,0) (sda) that has a size of 190.8 GB, which I can divide in two between Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Do these 190.8 GB correspond to the D: drive? If so, why do I have to divide it?

As I've already crashed my OS in the past trying to install a second OS, I want to be sure of what I'm doing, hence I ask: What should I do to install Ubuntu to the D: partition and allocate D: partition entirely to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't select the  "install ubuntu alongside windows" option.It will formats all the datas present in the partitions other than `c` drive.

It was much better to select the something else option.It will allows you to manually select the partition where ubuntu is going to be installed.

Ubuntu must be installed in ext4 partition.So open gparted and format the D drive to ext4 filesystem.Now run the ubuntu installer and then choose the **something else** option to install Ubuntu on `D` partition.

Comment: I remember that I have to prepare not one, but four partitions before installing Ubuntu with "something else" option. Is formatting only D drive to ext4 enough?

Comment: yes formatting only d drive to ext4 filesystem is enough.

Comment: The "install alongside Ubuntu" as far as I know will shrink the Windows system partition (here, it would be the C drive) and create a new partition where Ubuntu will be installed. I did use the option with my first Ubuntu dual-boot install, with no data loss in the Windows system partition or others; but yes as we always say, it's better to backup your data in case.... @LimboExile, since you want the drive D for Ubuntu, you should use the "something else" option.